# Boost text_oarchive constructor crashes on Android, not windows

Tags: android, boost, file-io, storage

I'm trying to port a game to Android, and I've been using boost for the saving / loading behaviour. The App now crashes when the save code is called. The crash occurs while trying to make text_oarchives, as with the following sample code:

```
void OHRMapArchiver::saveMap()
{
// copy some boost-incompatible data structures into ivar vectors
mapInstance->preSave();

CCLog("preSave");
std::ofstream outStream(MAP_SAVE_FILE);

CCLog("creating archive");
boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outStream);

CCLog("Outputting archive");
outputArchive << mapInstance;

// destroy all that stuff copied during pre-save
mapInstance->tileLoader.erase(mapInstance->tileLoader.begin(), mapInstance->tileLoader.end());
```

}

I sure could use some advice on why this might not be the case. I've given up on being able to debug on device, but the specific error I'm getting when

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outStream);
```

is called is "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdead (code=1), thread 1969 (Thread-112)". So segfault, but I can't imagine why, when as far as I know, it's only creating a wrapper around an ostream.

Other helpful clues... hm, I know I can create objects that implement serialize( Archive &ar, int version ), although I can't say for sure any objects have called it successfully yet. Possible linkage problems?

Also, file access permissions are enabled for App. At least, "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" " has been added to the manifest, and I can make and output files using std::ostream.write without crash. Also, as title implies, the win32 version works perfectly, outputting data as expected and reading back in without crash.

Using crystaX ndk r7, on device using Jelly Bean.

Any thoughts on why this crashes on Android?

EDIT: Update to this. According to boost aficionados, I was wrong in my assumption that Boost is incompatible with the most recent official release of the Android NDK. If user config files are properly defined, boost ought to compile just fine against the latest.

Instead, I hear rumblings that boost iostreams routinely crash with the Kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't an answer; I haven't found / can't find one of those. All I can recommend is that you simply not try to do what I am doing. At least, not with android NDK r8d.

After looking into ways to properly configure Boost to build without wchar support, which the NDK somewhat half-asses, code that works on windows crashes somewhere within the serialization / archive library in boost. I don't know where.

So yes, the answer is 'give up, preferably before wasting four months tracking solutions'.